# Matrix Compression

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a large matrix made up of only 1's and 0's. I want to compress this matrix into a smaller matrix for storage but need to be able to reproduce the original matrix. My thought is to use Eigenvalues to do this but I am not sure how... I started with the matrix below.

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

and got the eigenvalues to be $0,0,1+i,1-i$ and I am not sure what to do with these... or is there another way to compress the matrix?

**edit:** Here is the context of the problem... I have a large black and white image that I want to compress for storage so that it takes up less room in memory. The ones represent black and the zeros represent white. This is just a random matrix that I created so that I could understand the concept of compression by hand before I wrote a program for it. The only thing that I want to do with the compressed matrix is to recall it to the original size with minimum error.

Comment: This is a [well-studied topic](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=sparse+matrix+compression).

Comment: Often to decide which method to use it is good to know what do you want to do with the matrix and with its compression. For example, should you be able to easily add matrices by doing something to its compression? What about multiplication or linear operations in general? Are we only interested in minimizing the size of the compression? Should it be easy to parallelize computations?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 That the matrix is binary doesn't imply that it is sparse. They are not the same thing.

Comment: @Nathanson If there are more zeros than ones, then the matrix is sparse. If there are more ones than zeros, the complement is sparse, which adds one bit to the storage.

Comment: I do not see what is so special about the matrix that you can not use a general compression scheme (RLE to xz) on the bits.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Sparse storage may give no compression of data. They are not the same problem. Moreover, you are confused about what sparse is. Having at least half-plus-one zeros is not a criterion for sparse. You, may waste a lot of space if you use sparse storage for a matrix with that condition.

Comment: @Nathanson Fair enough. This question is a well-studied one though, and a basic internet search is the right place to start. Perhaps "binary matrix compression" would be a better search phrase.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Yes, indeed. My issue was only about the "sparse" part.

Comment: How big is your matrix, $10^3 \times 10^3$, $10^4 \times 10^4$ or what? Does it have any structure?

Comment: It is based on the size of a picture. lets say 1200x1800. this would be the number of pixels in a 4x6 picture.

Comment: A $1200 \times 1800$ binary matrix is tiny. It takes about $270$k bytes to store the bits. If the bits comes from a picture, then you can store them using an image format that support losseless compression. e.g. [lossless JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG) or [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics). There are high quality encoder/decoder around you can use. If you want to learn how to compress the bits yourself, I'll suggest you start with the models in lossless JPEG in how to predict the value of a pixel using nearby pixels.

Comment: @achillehui its the concept I need to understand/do by hand...